# Modify form action based on text input

Tags: jquery, forms, action

I'd like to modify the action attribute of the  element to include whatever text is typed into the  field. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, but can't:

```
<form action="/search/?searchoption=Audio&s=Blocks--[text input here]" method="post" name="audio-search-form">
    <input name="audiosearch" type="text" size="30" id="audiosearch">
    <input type="submit" name="audio-search-submit" value="Search Audio">
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your example form is all there is to it, why not just make the form method a GET request?

```
<form action="/search/" method="get" name="audio-search-form">
    <input name="searchoption" type="hidden" value="Audio">
    <input name="s" type="text" size="30" id="audiosearch">
    <input type="submit" name="audio-search-submit" value="Search Audio">
</form>
```

**edit:** argh! Sorry, I overlooked the `Blocks--` part that you want to prepend. I'll still leave this here for reference though, as this could be useful to you. (And if `Blocks--` is always going to be constant, you might just as well add it as a separate hidden field, or ditch it altogether and add it in the back-end.)

**edit 2:** to clarify, is there something wrong with the following resulting search url:

```
/search/?searchoption=Audio&type=Block--&s=whatever+the+search+input
```

which could be achieved with, for instance:

```
<form action="/search/" method="get" name="audio-search-form">
    <input name="searchoption" type="hidden" value="Audio">
    <input name="type" type="hidden" value="Block--">
    <input name="s" type="text" size="30" id="audiosearch">
    <input type="submit" name="audio-search-submit" value="Search Audio">
</form>
```

?

Comment: Right, that's the issue I have...the extra Blocks-- piece which is required for special type of result to be peformed.

Comment: @scotthorvath But is there something wrong with prepending it (by concatenating it) in the backend, or have it as a seperate form field, since it is going to be constant to begin with anyway? Does it necessarily have to be a part of the argument `s`?

Comment: I suppose not. I could probably do that and convert it to a get which might be easier. But then that wouldn't be challenging, would it? :) Thanks. I'll go that route.

Comment: `But then that wouldn't be challenging, would it? :)` I like your style @scotthorvath. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use can change form action using

```
 // Get input value
 input = $("#textboxId").val()

 // Change form action
 $("#formid").attr("action", "/requiredString/" + input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.attr('action', $form.find('input[type="text"]').val());
```

Or this you want to go **extreme**... :

```
$('form').attr('action', function(index, old) {
    return old + $(this).find('#audiosearch').val();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var initial = $("form").attr("action");
$("input[name=audiosearch]").bind("keyup",function(){
    $("form").attr("action",initial+$(this).val());
})​
```

Comment: I modified this slightly to this and not getting the input value passed to the action:

    `<script language="javascript">
$("input[name=audiosearch]").bind("keyup",function(){
   `$("audio-search-form").attr("action",$("audio-search-form").attr("action")+$(this).val());
})
</script>
<form method="post" action="/search/?searchoption=Audio&s=Blocks--" name="audio-search-form" id="audio-search-form">
 <input name="audiosearch" type="text" size="30" id="audiosearch">
 <input type="submit" name="audio-search-submit" value="Search Audio">
</form>`